# Idiomatic Haskell RLE in Purescript

Tags: haskell, purescript

So, I'm trying to learn Purescript by converting some Haskell code I had from the [99 Haskell Problems](http://haskell%2099%20problems%20github), and quickly got into a situation where I know how to solve it, but it is simply *too ugly™*. Here's the Haskell code for problems 10, 11 and 12; basically some RLE encode and decode functions:

```
-- Problem 10

rle :: Eq α => [α] -> [(Int, α)]
rle [] = []
rle (x:xs) = let (h, t) = span (== x) xs 
              in (length h + 1, x) : rle t

-- Problem 11

data RleItem α = Pair Int α | Single α deriving (Show)

encode :: Eq α => [α] -> [RleItem α]
encode = map unpack . rle 
   where unpack (1, x) = Single x
         unpack (y, x) = Pair y x

-- Problem 12

decode :: [RleItem α] -> [α]
decode = concatMap unroll
  where unroll (Pair y x) = replicate y x
        unroll (Single x) = [x]
```

I quickly learned that:

- There's no `[]` shorthand;
- There's no `(,)` tuples;
- We need to quantify polymorphic functions with an explicit `forall`;
- No pattern matching with `cons (:)` operator for the `Array` type;
- ...

So here's the question: *what is the most idiomatic way to write the above solution in Purescript*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There's no [] shorthand

In PureScript we explicitly call the type constructor `List`

> There's no (,) tuples

In PureScript we either use the `Tuple` type, or another common pattern is to use records with descriptive names, like I did in my solution below.

> We need to quantify polymorphic functions with an explicit forall

yes

> No pattern matching with cons (:) operator for the Array type

We can pattern match on the `List` type with `:`. Pattern matching the head of an `Array` is almost never a good idea as it's very bad for performance.

I've translated your solution into PureScript using the points mentioned above. The example can also be tried and run at: http://try.purescript.org/?gist=f45651a7f4d134d466d575b1c4dfb614&backend=core

```
-- Problem 10

rle :: forall a. (Eq a) => List a -> List {repetitions :: Int, value :: a}
rle Nil = Nil
rle (x:xs) = case span (_ == x) xs of
  {init: h, rest: t} -> {repetitions: length h + 1, value: x} : rle t

-- Problem 11

data RleItem a = Pair Int a | Single a

encode :: forall a. Eq a => List a -> List (RleItem a)
encode = map unpack <<< rle 
   where 
    unpack = case _ of
      {repetitions: 1, value} -> Single value
      {repetitions, value} -> Pair repetitions value

-- Problem 12

decode :: forall a. List (RleItem a) -> List a
decode = concatMap unroll
  where unroll (Pair y x) = replicate y x
        unroll (Single x) = singleton x
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my own answer so far (albeit not completely 1:1), though I don't expect to accept it:

```
data RleItem α = Pair Int α | Single α

encode :: forall α. (Eq α) => List α -> List (RleItem α)
encode Nil = Nil
encode p@(x:_) = let s = span ((==) x) p in
  pack (length s.init) : encode s.rest where
    pack 0 = Single x
    pack y = Pair y x

decode :: forall α. List (RleItem α) -> List α
decode = (=<<) unpack where
  unpack (Single x) = pure x
  unpack (Pair y x) = replicate y x
```